# VideoJs player ignoring preload

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, video.js, preload

I'm at a loss for why this is happening and am failing to come up with an effective, non-hacky solution. I have a ReactJs Video component that features a simple implementation of a videojs player. I'm using it to play mpeg-dash files. For some reason, no matter what I set for preload (either on the html5 element or as options for the player), all of the players are downloading the video files all at once. This is severely affecting performance since they are HD videos and amount to over 250Mb. Here is the init method that I run when mounting the component:

```
  initVideoPlayer() {
    const { videoPath, videoFileName, mobileVideoFileName } = this.props;
    if (this.videoNode) {
      let mimeType;
      let fullVideoPath;
      let isIOS;

      if (isIOS) {
        fullVideoPath = `${videoPath}/${mobileVideoFileName}.m3u8`;
        mimeType = 'application/x-mpegURL';
      } else {
        fullVideoPath = `${videoPath}/${videoFileName}.mpd`;
        mimeType = 'application/dash+xml';
      }

      console.log(fullVideoPath);

      this.state.videoJsOptions = {
        autoplay: false,
        controls: false,
        preload: 'none',
        sources: [
          {
            mimeType,
            src:fullVideoPath,
          },
        ],
      };

      this.videoJsPlayer = videojs(this.videoNode, this.state.videoJsOptions);
    }
  }
```

And the html element

```
if (videoFileName) {
  return (
    <div data-vjs-player>
      <video
        className="video-js"
        key="desktop"
        ref={(node) => {
          this.videoNode = node;
        }}
        muted={this.state.isVideoMuted}
        playsInline
        poster={poster}
        // preload="metadata"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Has anyone experienced this problem before?

Comment: did you get any solution please let me know or post here. thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

video.js' preload attribute expect to recieve string not boolean. Available options: 'auto', 'metadata', 'none'.

Comment: It might help if you directly fix OP's code with proper formatting. I suggest you read [answer]

Comment: @Rojo Are you suggesting Mnemonic Pie make an edit to my question or offer a change to my code in *their* answer? Because changing a boolean to a non-boolean string is not a formatting issue.

Comment: Sorry, but my code does reflect that --> *preload: 'none',*